# Commerce: save quantity button removing products

Tags: views, theming, commerce

I've come across a frustrating issue after adding a cart view block on my page in the form of a "sidebar". When trying to update a quantity or just clicking the "save" button (at bottom of the view) itself will remove the first line item added to the cart. Finally, a message shows on the next page saying: "line item removed."

I have disabled all non essential and potentially problematic modules. There is no custom Javascript / AJAX written for this button. I've checked the error logs and there is nothing wrong there.

Oddly enough, the feature works fine on our live site using a different theme. I have exported the views and ensured they are both exactly the same.

Does anyone have a clue what might be causing this? Or, any debugging steps I could try out?

Note: I'm on Commerce Kickstart 2.x-2.19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that I had written some javascript to change the value attribute of the "save" input to "update". After changing it back to "save" the button works just fine and nothing is removed from the cart.

To confirm, I went to a different theme and changed the value attribute of the "save" button to "foo" and it started removing line items from the cart.